# Remove file name “specification.php?url=” from url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

This is a link on **index.php** page

```
<a href="specification.php?url=<?= $mbbelow['url']; ?>"><?= $mbbelow['brand_name']; ?><?= $mbbelow['title']; ?></a>
```

from this link I come on page **specification.php**
then this **url** come **http://www.themobilesapp.com/specification.php?url=Sony-Xperia-Z5-specifications-5246.php**

in the base of **url** I find all data of page.

This url is not proper according to me. 
Here I want to remove **specification.php?url=** from this above url.
Please tell me in proper and full explain way that how to remove and make new url like this
**http://www.themobilesapp.com/Sony-Xperia-Z5-specifications-5246.php**

I only need **.htaccess** or I also need to work using php code to remove this.

I will provide you all details you need here for to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ specification.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ specification.php?url=$1
```